# how to resolve the error of out of memory for YOLOV8 model for model being trained on GPU in local machine

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, gpu, nvidia, yolov8

I  have this script

```
import ultralytics
from ultralytics import YOLO

import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()
ultralytics.checks()
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    # Load a model
    model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')  # load a pretrained model (recommended for training)

    # Train the model
    model.train(data='data.yaml', epochs=2, imgsz=832, device=0)

    # Load our custom goat model
    model = YOLO("runs/detect/train/weights/best.pt")
```

for this I am having the NVIDIA-SMI as

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 511.69       Driver Version: 511.69       CUDA Version: 11.6     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ... WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   47C    P8     3W /  N/A |      0MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I ran the following 2 codes before running the script above

```
conda create -n ENV_NAME python=3.7
conda activate ENV_NAME
pip install ultralytics

conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.6 -c pytorch -c nvidia
conda install cudatoolkit
```

but when I am running this code I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\aftab\.conda\envs\pytorch_env\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\aftab\.conda\envs\pytorch_env\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
MemoryError
raise err
OSError: [WinError 1455] The paging file is too small for this operation to complete. Error loading "C:\Users\aftab\.conda\envs\pytorch_env\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\cudnn_adv_infer64_8.dll" or one of its dependencies.
```

I have also tried to increase the memory in Advanced settings of PC till 8092 MB. What else can I do
is it possible to debug this error as I want to run the YOLOV8 model on my local machine